# Why my select dropdown shown as radio list in mobile?

Tags: html, angular, forms

I create a web application using Angular 10, but my client complaining to me about `<select>` input that shown as popup dialog containing radio list in the mobile browser like image below:

[image: in Google Chrome browser]     [image: in Opera Touch browser]

Here's the code in project file:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="ID_ROUTE_NETWORK">
  <option hidden selected>Pilih Rute Pengiriman...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of orderOptions.rute" [ngValue]='option'>
    {{option.KOTA_ASAL | titlecase}} - {{option.KOTA_TUJUAN | titlecase}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Final markup in the element inspector:

```
<select _ngcontent-qao-c67="" formcontrolname="ID_ROUTE_NETWORK" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="ID_ROUTE_NETWORK">
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" hidden="" selected="">Pilih Rute Pengiriman...</option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="1: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Jayapura </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="2: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Nabire </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="3: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Sorong </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="4: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Manokwari </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="5: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Serui </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="6: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Biak </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="7: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Merauke </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="8: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Surabaya - Agats </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="9: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Nabire - Surabaya </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="10: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Manokwari - Surabaya </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="11: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Serui - Surabaya </option>
  <option _ngcontent-qao-c67="" value="12: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted"> Biak - Surabaya </option>
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
    }-->
</select>
```

Is there any suspect or explanation about it? And How to force it to show as normal options dropdown like in desktop?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show the markup for the select? Also it's worth mentioning that mobile browsers handle native browser `select`s with a dialog box, both Chrome and Safari do this but I have never seen a radio list appearing..

Comment: @camaulay okay, I've added it in the post